# openssl hex2bn and bn2hex will not original string, but always a long postfix

Tags: openssl, bignum

Playing with openssl BN_hex2bn and BN_bn2hex.  Expecting to get the original string after hex2bn and then bn2hex, but always got a longer string, with the first past the same as the original string, but a long post fix.  Followin gis the code

```
BIGNUM* test2 = BN_new();
BN_hex2bn(&test2, argv[1]);
char * number_str_test2 = BN_bn2hex(test2);
printf("Input hex string test2 is %s\n", number_str_test2);
```

Running result:

```
 >./a.out 10000000000000000
 >Input hex string test2 is 100000000000000030344079B87F000010
```

Please note the post fix 3034407....

Comment: That should be `number_str_test2` instead of `number_str` in the `printf`

Comment: that was a typo, there is no number_str in the code.